# BASH timeout command as xargs command

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, timeout, pipeline, xargs

This is my first post here. I am a hobbyist.

I am on an RPi4 running "Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)".

A pipeline gets the power status of a bunch of hard drives. However, on some drives hdparm becomes unresponsive.

To try to solve this I used the timeout command followed by hdparm as argument to an xargs in a pipeline, but the timeout now times-out xargs rather than hdparm.

The pipeline works fine until the last section that is the xargs command:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep -f /home/dec/drivelist| cut -d '/' -f 3 | xargs -I {} timeout -k 10 8 hdparm -C /dev/{}
```

<sub>( drivelist Is an ASCII file that just has a single disk UUID on each line. )</sub>

This outputs the following and times-out at sda2 where it exits and fails to continue xargs.

```
/dev/sdf1:
 drive state is:  standby

/dev/sdd1:
 drive state is:  standby

/dev/sdg1:
 drive state is:  standby

/dev/sda2:
xargs: timeout: terminated by sig
```

The problem here is that the timeout actually times out xargs (or the entire pipe?) rather than just hdparm.

I have tried:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep -f /home/dec/drivelist| cut -d '/' -f 3 | xargs -I {} bash -C "timeout -k 10 8 hdparm -C /dev/{}"
```

which does not work as desired either and outputs:

```
bash: timeout -k 10 8 hdparm -C /dev/sdf1: No such file or directory
bash: timeout -k 10 8 hdparm -C /dev/sdd1: No such file or directory
bash: timeout -k 10 8 hdparm -C /dev/sdg1: No such file or directory
bash: timeout -k 10 8 hdparm -C /dev/sda2: No such file or directory
```

How do I make this work in a pipeline, avoiding multiline code?

Thanks for your time and help.

vLAd

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION RE. HDPARM**

hdparm -C seems to hang checking, for example, a 2.7 TB volume. This volume is connected to the RPi via SATA-USB and plugged into a USB3 port.

Could hdparm -C on such a size perhaps need several minutes to complete and am I just impatient?

**EDIT**

I have added this to the pipeline, just before the xargs, but to no avail; this drops the number, so sdXn becomes just sdX.

```
grep -Eo "[a-z]{3}"
```

Comment: The second shown output shows that there is no further drive after `sda2`, so I conclude that the original version works and there's simply nothing _to continue xargs_.

Comment: Hi Armali, to keep the post shorter, I chopped the output after sda2, there is more. Sorry.

Comment: *"hdparm -C  ... need several minutes to complete ..."* . Test it separate on the command line and then document that in the script? Also, possibly adding `--verbose` to your `xargs` cmd-line may show information that is helpful. Good luck. (and Good first post!)

Comment: Tested, shellter, hdparm does eventually exit with code 22, but it takes more than a minute. With the other drives it completes almost instantly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of
`bash -C "timeout -k 10 8 hdparm -C /dev/{}"`
did you mean
`bash -c "timeout -k 10 8 hdparm -C /dev/{}"`
?

The upper- and lower-case "[Cc]" arguments to `bash` mean very different things...

Comment: The second output above is for bash -C, which I tried after bash -c, both do not yield what I'm looking for.

Comment: Recommend editing your post to include the `bash -c` output as that's probably closer to what you want, then if there's errors with it someone might be able to help with that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that `xargs` stops executing commands when it encounters the exit status caused by a timeout.  One way to fix the problem is to stop using `xargs`.  Try replacing

```
xargs -I {} timeout -k 10 8 hdparm -C /dev/{}
```

with

```
while read -r dev; do timeout -k 10 8 hdparm -C "/dev/$dev"; done
```

Comment: Thanks pjh, I think I can do something with that.